# How to add a conditional statement for JQUERY AJAX response function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

This is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".jlk").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var task = jQuery(this).attr("data-task");
        var post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id");
        var nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce");
        var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');

        jQuery(".status-" + post_id).html("&nbsp;&nbsp;").addClass("loading-img").show();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: wtilp.ajax_url,
            data: { action: "wti_like_post_process_vote", task: task, post_id: post_id, nonce: nonce },
            success: function (response) {            
                jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html(response.like);
                jQuery(".unlc-" + post_id).html(response.unlike);
                jQuery(".status-" + post_id).removeClass("loading-img").empty().html(response.msg);
            }
        });
    });

    // Other users tooltip
    jQuery("span.wti-others-like").live("mouseover", function () {
        jQuery(this).children("span").show();
    });

    jQuery("span.wti-others-like").live("mouseout", function () {
        jQuery(this).children("span").hide();
    });
});
```

And I'm trying to add the conditional statement like this :

```
if (jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html(response.like)) {
                    $(".action-unlike-" + post_id + " img").removeClass('opacity-none'); $(".action-like-" + post_id + " img").addClass('opacity-none'); alert('positive');        
                }
                else if (jQuery(".unlc-" + post_id).html(response.unlike)) { $(".action-like-" + post_id + " img").removeClass('opacity-none'); $(".action-unlike-" + post_id + " img").addClass('opacity-none'); alert('negative'); }
```

But it always alert 'positive' like its not reading my conditions.

How can i accomplish this?

If (response.like == 'true') {do this} else if (response.unlike == 'true') {do this} ?

Comment: `html` method as a setter returns an object which is a truthy value, so ... . Is that supposed to be `jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html() === response.like`?

Comment: Describe the case in which you want `jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html(response.like)` to cause an alert negative.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.html` returns the jQuery collection which evaluates to `true`, so your condition is _always_ true. What exactly did you want your `if` to check for?

Comment: Theres two buttons... One for like a post the other to dislike... i want to check if user click on response.like or response.unlike and do my code for each one

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery HTML Method always returns true since it is a method to set HTML when you pass in a value.

See: http://api.jquery.com/html/

If your HTML is an input string your looking for the "Val" Method.

See: http://api.jquery.com/val/

if you literally want to check the HTML you need to check the .html() with NO Values passed in. Then do a string or other comparison of that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

H i,

The if statement is a declaration ( it is setting html, not getting html and checking  )

```
  if (jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html(response.like)) { ...
```

do you mean to do :

```
 if (jQuery(".lc-" + post_id).html()===response.like) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should actually check the HTML value like `$(".lc-" + post_id).html()` with the `response.like` instead of setting the value in it. You can replace the code with the below one:

```
if ($(".lc-" + post_id).html() == response.like) {
    $(".action-unlike-" + post_id + " img").removeClass('opacity-none');
    $(".action-like-" + post_id + " img").addClass('opacity-none');
    alert('positive');
} else if ($(".unlc-" + post_id).html() == response.unlike) {
    $(".action-like-" + post_id + " img").removeClass('opacity-none');
    $(".action-unlike-" + post_id + " img").addClass('opacity-none');
    alert('negative');
}
```

Good luck!